# How to fix GridBagConstraint's anchor with custom component?

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, gridbaglayout

I made a custom component so I could display images and the like, but it refuses to use anchor properly and centers at the top. Does anyone have a fix? Also, if anyone can point me to an easier layout I might switch, but I already use a lot of GridBag so it would be hard.

Test class for general testing:

```
package com.launcher.test;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.launcher.swing.ModViewer;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

public Test() {
    super("Super Installer");
    JPanel j = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    addObjs(j);
    this.add(j);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void addObjs(JPanel j) {
    setGBC(0, 0);
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 2;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    j.add(new ModViewer(), gbc);
    setGBC(2, 0);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    j.add(new JButton("Add Mod"));
}

private void setGBC(int i, int j) {
    gbc.gridx = i;
    gbc.gridy = j;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}

}
```

ModViewer class, essentially a box:

```
package com.launcher.swing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.launcher.Main;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ModViewer extends JPanel {

public ModViewer() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 250, 250)));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get positioning to work for the `GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST` anchor position, you need to set the weight in the X axis:

```
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I couldn't figure it out, but now it works great!